# Getting URL after InvokeWebRequest, when Status Code is 200 and store in CSV

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I am attempting to pull the URL once an InvokeWebRequest has been called in my script. I wish for it do this when the HTTP Status Code is 200. So far, I have got it to tell the Status Code, and give the re-directed URL is 301/302 is the Status Code. Also an Error Message when the Status Code is 4xx//5xx.

I deal with a lot of URLs on clients' ecommerce sites, so need know what the final URL is after a end-user clicks on one of the URLs - essentially something like the query strings being dropped or something like that, on Status Code 200. As mentioned before, I already have 3xx/4xx/5xx reporting.

Attempted -

1. Reading the page and pulling the URL from the Header
2. Searching for the 'href' and pulling it

I wish for the CSV out to have the following output -

[Expected CSV Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um6JX.png)

[Actual CSV Output (Row 3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsLzc.png)

The "Landing Page" field is what I am trying to fill - the rest are working.

Script below -

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$urlInput = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\testurls.txt"
$csvOutput = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\testurl_result.csv"

#$totalUrls = Get-Content $urlInput | Measure-Object –Line
#Write-Host "Total URLs = $totalUrls" 

$results = Test-Path "C:\Users\User\Desktop\testurl_result.csv"

If ($results -eq $false) {
    Remove-Item "testurl_result.csv" -Force
}

Get-Content $urlInput | ForEach-Object { $uri = $_; 
    try 
    { 
        Start-Sleep 5
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        $link = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    }
    catch 
    {
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Error = $_}
    } 
} | Select-Object @{Name='Click URL'; Expression={$uri}}, StatusCode, @{Name='Path'; Expression={([uri]$uri).AbsolutePath}}, @{Name='UTMs'; Expression={([uri]$uri).Query}}, @{Name='RedirectTo';Expression={$_.Headers["Location"]}}, @{Name='Landing Page';Expression={$link.Links | select -ExpandProperty href}}, Error | Export-Csv $csvOutput -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks.

Comment: But you already now the URI - it's stored in `$uri`?

Comment: For debugging use Format-Table.  So add line after $link =  : $link | Format-Table

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Correct, the URI is stored in that var. But I need to know if the query strings were dropped from the URL after the page loads.